# Twilio Streaming lose GaussianBlurBackgroundProcessor

Tags: twilio

I tried to set GaussianBlurBackgroundProcessor (I use [this post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/change-background-video-calls-twilio-video-processors-library) as a starting point but instead of node.js i use *.min.js in a php page). On local video it works but when I connect my video in a room, remote partecipants see my video "clean".
Someone had have my same problem?

I use min version of:

- twilio-video.js 2.22.1
- twilio-video-processors.js 1.0.2

This is the code:

```
[...]
    const TWVideo = Twilio.Video;

    const bg = new Twilio.VideoProcessors.GaussianBlurBackgroundProcessor({
        assetsPath: '',
        maskBlurRadius: 5,
        blurFilterRadius: 25,
    });
    bg.loadModel();
    
    const localVideo = TWVideo.createLocalVideoTrack().then(track => {
        let video = document.getElementById('local-media').firstElementChild;

        setProcessor(bg, track);
        video.appendChild(track.attach());
        $('#local-media').find('video').css('width', '200px');
    });
    
    TWVideo.connect(room_token, {
        name: roomName
    }).then(room => {
        window.room = activeRoom = room;
        log('Connected to Room '+ roomName);
        
        room.participants.forEach(participantConnected);
        room.on('participantConnected', participantConnected);
        
        room.on('participantDisconnected', participantDisconnected);
        room.once('disconnected', error => room.participants.forEach(participantDisconnected));
        
        room.on('reconnecting', error => {
            assert.equal(room.state, 'reconnecting');
            if (error.code === 53001) {
                console.log('Reconnecting your signaling connection!', error.message);
            } 
            else if (error.code === 53405) {
                console.log('Reconnecting your media connection!', error.message);
            }
        });

        room.on('reconnected', () => {
            console.log('Reconnected your signaling and media connections!');
            assert.equal(room.state, 'connected');
        });
        
        room.on('participantReconnected', remoteParticipant => {
            console.log("${remoteParticipant.identity} has reconnected the signaling connection to the Room!");
            assert.equals(remoteParticipant.state, 'connected');
        })
    });
[...]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to show the local video and add the video track to the room?

Comment: @philnash I have modified the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating a local video track and applying the blur to it, but you’re not using that track when you connect to the room. I would create the local video track and audio track first, then apply them to the room when you connect like this:

```
Video.connect(roomToken, {
  name: roomName,
  tracks: [localVideo, localAudio]
}).then(…);
```

Comment: Thanks philnash! One thing that is not clear to me: I thought that the creation of the "localVideo" directly included the audio. How should I create the audio part (localAudio) separately? Do you have any referral links? Or I could attach only local video => tracks: [localVideo]?

Comment: When using `createLocalVideoTrack` you only ask for camera access and only get a video track. You can also use `createLocalAudioTrack` to do the same for audio, or collect them together with [`createLocalTracks`](https://sdk.twilio.com/js/video/releases/2.24.0/docs/module-twilio-video.html#.createLocalTracks__anchor).